# How to resolve path issues while moving files in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get a file from html form and store it in another folder. It's basically cloud function, and I am new to both node.js and firebase so don't know what I am doing wrong. What I manage to do is:

```
const fileMiddleware = require('express-multipart-file-parser');

app.post("/sendMail", (req, res) => {
const {
    fieldname,
    filename,
    encoding,
    mimetype,
    buffer,
  } = req.files[0];
  console.log(req.files[0].originalname);
  var fs = require('fs')

  var oldPath = req.files[0].originalname;
  var newPath = '/functions/'+oldPath;

  fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('Successfully renamed - AKA moved!')
  });
});
```

Whenever I try to move file, I got path issues. The error is as follows:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Maisum Abbas\now\functions\sendMail.txt' 
> 'C:\functions\sendMail.txt'] {    
>    errno: -4058,
>    code: 'ENOENT',
>    syscall: 'rename',
>    path: 'C:\\Users\\Maisum Abbas\\now\\functions\\sendMail.txt',
>    dest: 'C:\\functions\\sendMail.txt'
>  }
```

Also, this is the path where I want to actually move the file but oldpath is already setup like this.

```
C:\Users\Maisum Abbas\now\functions\sendMail.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I needed to attach a file with email, it was causing path issues. I tried it with multer and it works. What I did:

```
//call libraries here

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'resume/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('filetoupload');

app.post("/careerMail", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  const { email } = req.body;
  const { phone } = req.body;
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
  });

const dest = 'mymail';

const mailOptions = {
    from: email, // Something like: Jane Doe <janedoe@gmail.com>
    to: dest,
    subject: 'Candidate Application', // email subject
    html: `<div>             
    <strong>From:</strong> ` +
          name +
          `<br /><br />              
    <strong>Email:</strong> ` +
          email +
          `<br /><br />              
    <strong>Phone:</strong> ` +
          phone +
          `<br /><br />           
    </div>           
    `,// email content in HTML
    attachments: [
      {
          filename: req.files[0].originalname,
          content: req.files[0].buffer.toString("base64"),
          encoding: "base64"
      }
    ]

and rest of the code...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rethinking this approach altogether.  You won't be able to move files around in a deployed function.  The [nodejs runtime filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) doesn't allow any files to be written anywhere in the filesystem, except for `os.tmpdir()` (which is /tmp on Linux).

If you need to write a file temporarily, you should definitely only use that tmp space.  Be aware that files written there occupy memory and should be deleted before the function terminates, or you could leak memory.

You can read files that you deployed with your code, but you should do that through relative paths.

Comment: I just need file to attach it as an attachment and send email, for that I just need the rigth path, if somehow I am able to do that, then I don't have to move files. But, for some reason it only checks the filepath where my index.js is, that's why I am trying to move it. But, if there is any way that can be done without moving files, please let me know. I have gone through various posts but nothing works for me or I couldn't do it properly may be.

Comment: if you know the attachment name you can do get the root path then concatenate the location, like ```filePath = rootPath + '/foldernames/+fileName;

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem while moving file. I sort this problem by using a function to get the application root folder and then concatenate rest of the location.

```
//place this file on application root.
//import where you need to get the root path.

const path = require('path');
module.exports = (function(){
    return path.dirname(require.main.filename || process.mainModule.filename);
})();

//taking your case move location.

const rootPath = //require the above module.

const newPath = rootPath + /functions/' +oldPath;

 fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('Successfully renamed - AKA moved!')
  });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it create problems once you deploy it since the root path will be on your system? Also, wouldn't this also create problem if you upload your file from some other path, just a thought? I am totally new to node.js so can;t say if I am making much sense.

Comment: This will not create any problem on server. 
If you want to upload your file from other directory you just concatenate ```newPath = rootPath + folderWhereToUpload+whateverFileNameYouWant; ```

Comment: Can you show me how are you importing your root path?

Comment: create a file on project root and name it like root.js and then paste the ```const path = require('path');
module.exports = (function(){
    return path.dirname(require.main.filename || process.mainModule.filename);
})();``` And  import this file wherever you like. I need to see your directory structure where u r requiring this file.

Comment: If your file is one folder deep import like this ```const rootPath = require('./root');``, Search on google how to import file from different level in nodejs.

Comment: I manage to do it with multer since I needed to attach my file with email and it works. Didn't try your method but thank you so much for the support.